# How can I detect the SPACE KeyEvent anywhere in my JavaFX app?

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I want to detect a `KeyEvent` regardless of what element has focus in my JavaFX app - in particular, I want to detect the `SPACE` key. I tried to add a listener to the `Scene` that corresponds to my window:

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(ev -> {
    if (ev.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        System.out.println("GOOD");
    }
});
```

But if I have a particular node with focus (like a `ListView` or `Button`) then it won't be detected.

How can I detect when the `SPACE` key is pressed regardless of whatever the user is doing in my app? I don't intend to *interrupt* whatever node is receiving the `KeyEvent` - I just want to *know* if it happens. One (ugly) solution would be adding the listener to all my nodes, but I would rather not if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect the KeyEvent by adding an event filter to the root node

Here is a quick example using some of the controls you mentioned:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        TextField textfield = new TextField();
        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.getItems().add("One");
        listView.getItems().add("Two");
        listView.getItems().add("Three");
        Button button = new Button("Button");

        VBox root = new VBox(5, textfield, listView, button);
        root.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event->{
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                System.out.println("GOOD");
            }
        });
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Note: On controls that generate a popup / overlay, a space might not be detected while it is showing, but will be detected when hidden yet still in focus. You can see this behaviour if you add a ComboBox or ColorPicker to the above example

Comment: So basically it's not possible to reliable detect a space key.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your code

```
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event ->{
        if(event.getCode()== KeyCode.SPACE)
        {
            System.out.println("goog luck");
        }

        });
```

Comment: This is total rubbish: It doesn't answer the question and the code isn't even correct.